# How to specify the region of convergence in `inverse_laplace_transform` function of SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy

In the documentation of SymPy, it says:

> The plane can be specified by argument `plane`, but will be inferred if passed as None.

However, there are no examples of methods used to specify this plane. I'm trying to find the inverse Laplace transform of the same function with different regions of convergence, but I'm unable to do so.

Here's my code:

```py
from sympy import *
var('t,s')
F1 = 1/((s)*(s+1))
f1 = inverse_laplace_transform(F1,s,t,re(s)<-1)
print(f1)

F2 = 1/((s)*(s+1))
f2 = inverse_laplace_transform(F2,s,t,re(s)>0)
print(f2)

F3 = 1/((s)*(s+1))
f3 = inverse_laplace_transform(F3,s,t,-1<re(s)<0)
print(f3)
```

But, my output is:

```
Heaviside(t) - exp(-t)*Heaviside(t)
Heaviside(t) - exp(-t)*Heaviside(t)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Error Message--
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

The output I expected was:

```
Heaviside(t) - exp(-t)*Heaviside(t)
exp(-t)*Heaviside(-t) - Heaviside(-t)
-Heaviside(-t) - exp(-t)*Heaviside(t)
```

Comment: There is an example in the sympy tests that passes `plane=0`. Looking at the code though it's not clear where the plane argument is actually used though.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin Please show me, I'm unable to locate it... Also, is there any other information on using it?

Comment: @moderators I request you to migrate this to the DSP Stack Exchange. This is probably more suitable for that website since I've received a very low response. If not, then please tell me how I can get a solution to this problem on this website itself. If I don't get any responses from moderators, I'll have to delete and repost on DSP manually, that's not something I want to do though

Comment: I don't think that you will get any better help anywhere else since this is a sympy question.

Comment: It might be better posted as an issue for sympy on github though

Comment: @OscarBenjamin Thanks for your suggestion. Posting on GitHub now, and if it answers the question, I'll link it here